# Extend class response in PHP

Tags: php, object, sqlite, class-extensions

I'm working in a project using mySQL and SQLite DB. My goal is to make the code able to work with both database types. I developed the code for mySQL, using the `mysqli` class, and now I want to modify it to make it also work with `SQLite3` objects.

`SQLite3` class implements the same methods as `mysqli` (at least, those than I use), but sometimes using different names. For example, `mysqli::fetch_array()` becomes `SQLite3::fechArray()`. So I'm extending SQLite3 and `SQLite3Result` classes to implement the methods I need. For example:

```
class SQLite3ResultEx extends SQLite3Result {
    public function fetch_array() {
        return parent::fetchArray();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do for extending the response for `SQLite3` class to get my own `SQLite3Response` extended class. I mean:

```
class SQLite3Ex extends SQLite3 {
    public function __construct($filename, $flags = null, $encryption_key = null) {
        return parent::__construct($filename, $flags, $encryption_key);
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $res = parent::query($query);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Now `$res` is an `SQLite3Result` object, but I need it becomes a `SQLite3ResultEx` object (my own extended class).

Comment: I can recommend a good read: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: Yeah, I understand. The right way is to use my own PDO class, so this assures all the methods are available independently the database I use. I'll try doing this. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Actually I suggest to use the PDO classes built into PHP. Why would you write it your own when it's ready to use?

Comment: This is not that I meant. I was talking about to do a class who uses PDO classes (maybe extending it), not creating a full PDO class. This way, I can add methods to change the target database at any moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to abstract it a bit further, instead of extending `SQLite3Result`, you could create a new class that would accept a `SQLite3Result` object, provide its own methods which then proxy to the result.

```
class myResults
{
    /**
     * @var SQLite3Result
     */
    protected $result;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param SQLite3Result $result
     */
    public function __construct(SQLite3Result $result)
    {
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch array of results
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetch_array()
    {
        return $this->result->fetchArray();
    }

    // Any other methods you need
}
```

Then your `SQLite3Ex::query` method becomes:

```
/**
 * Preform query
 * @param string $query
 * @return myResults
 */
public function query($query)
{
    $res = parent::query($query);
    return new myResults($res);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try and create $res as a specific parameter of your subclass and reference it directly with

```
$this->res = ...
```

so that your subclass looks like:

```
class SQLite3Ex extends SQLite3 {
 private $res;
    public function __construct($filename, $flags = null, $encryption_key = null) {
        return parent::__construct($filename, $flags, $encryption_key);
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $this->res = parent::query($query);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand what're you suggestting. The problem is not to get $res, but making $res becomes a SQLiteResultEx object (now it's a SQLiteResult class object).